# '<' not supported between instances of 'Tech' and 'Mobile' in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

hello i'm trying to make `two model inside one view (def) to show data in one html page`

i did this in views.py but it say `'<' not supported between instances of 'Tech' and 'Mobile'` i don't know what is the problem

Views.py :

```
def home(request):
    mobileforhome = Mobile.objects.all()
    techforhome = Tech.objects.all()
    results = list(sorted(chain(mobileforhome,techforhome)))

    paginator = Paginator(results,6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    results = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {'results':results}
    return render(request,'website_primary_html_pages/home.html',context=context)
```

Comment: What should be the sort criteria? How should the models be ordered? By default django model instances are not orderable/sortable; you need to implement the ordering API or use a key function in `sorted()`

Comment: okay thanks can you give me a example please i mean code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Django model instances are not orderable/sortable; the easiest solution would be to use a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) in  [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to define the order.

For example, if you want to sort by the ID field of both models:

```
results = list(
    sorted(
        chain(mobileforhome, techforhome),
        key=lambda x: x.id))
```